# python failed to check module which I installed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed a module named "Image" in python 3.6 using pip doing:
    `pip install Image`
it installed successfully. But when I tried to import this into my script it produced an error.
Here is what happened

```
import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'
```

When i tried to reinstall it pip says all the requirements are satisfied.

```
C:\Users\abc>pip install Image
Requirement already satisfied: Image in c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: django in c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from Image)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from Image)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from django->Image)
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pillow->Image)
```

Any help to solve this issue.... or anyother package to download googlemaps of a partucular area at high resolution

Comment: yes. It produces same results, i.e. all requirements satisfied

Answer (score 0):

This is a small confusion you will get use to in Python world. The name of the package and the name of the module can be different. In your case, try to replace `import Image` with `import image`.